Better performance and results for autocomplete search edge_ngram or search_as_you_type elasticsearch
I was testing and researching about the use of edge_ngrams and the search_as_you_type field in Elasticsearch to improve search results, but I see that they are very similar and I would like to know which one has better performance and results.
I saw both of them bring good results, in my opinion I saw that the search_as_you_type field saves even more elements in the index because it saves the shingles and large prefixes of the field, but since it is an Elasticsearch field type it may have better performance and some hidden things,
thanks
